# SwiftUI: How would I make stretchable (flexible) sticky header for ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

Well, honestly, I did it, because I needed it, and only then looked around and did not find anything on SO native in SwiftUI, so wanted to share. Thus this is just a self-answered question.

Initially I needed sticky stretchable sticky header for lazy content dependent only on `ScrollView`.

Later (after I got my solution) I found [this one on Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-create-a-stretchable-header-with-parallax-scrolling-4a98faeeb262), but I don't like it (and would not recommend at least as-is), because:

1. overcomplicated (many unneeded code, many unneeded calculations)
2. depends (and joins) with safe area only, so limited applicability
3. based on `offset` (I don't like to use offset, because of its inconsistency with layout, etc.)
4. it is not sticky and to make it sticky it is needed even more code

So, actually all this text was just to fulfil SO question requirements - who knows me here knows that I don't like to type many text, it is better to type code , in short - my approach is below in answer, maybe someone find it useful.

Initial code which SwiftUI gives us for free

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 8, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
        Section {
            ForEach(0...100) {
                Text("Item \($0)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 60)
            }
        } header: {
           Image("picture").resizable().scaledToFill()
               .frame(height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Header is sticky by scrolling up, but not when down (dragged with content), and it is not stretchable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### iOS 15.5 (initial)

[image: demo]

Ok, we need to solve two problems:

1. make top of header pinned to top of `ScrollView` on drag down
2. stretch header on drag down to make header content (image in majority of cases) scale to fill

A possible approach to solve this:

1. `ScrollView` now manages content offsets privately (UIKit variants are out of topics here), so to pin to top using overlay

```
    ScrollView {
        // ...
    }
    .overlay(
        // >> any header
        Image("picture").resizable().scaledToFill()
        // << header end
            .frame(height: imageHeight)  // will calculate below
            .clipped()
```

2. Use `Section` default header (as placeholder) to calculate current distance from `ScrollView` top

   ```
    Section(...) {
      // ...
    } header: {
        // here is only caculable part
        GeometryReader {
            // detect current position of header bottom edge
            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                value: $0.frame(in: .named("area")).maxY)
        }
        .frame(height: headerHeight)
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
            // prevent image negative height if header is not pinned 
            // for simplicity (can be optional, etc.)
            imageHeight = $0 < 0 ? 0.001 : $0
        }
    }
   ```

That's actually it, everything else is just for demo part.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestFlexibleStickyHeader.swift)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you need solution based on **ScrollView**:

1/ find **scrollOffset** (see example or use [ScrollViewWithScrollOffset](https://github.com/Jnis/ScrollViewWithScrollOffset))

2/ wrap image with **GeometryReader** to avoid frame glitches and get normal image size on device screen

3/ use size from GeometryReader and scrollOffset to set image frame

Full code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    private let coordinateSpaceName = "scrollViewSpaceName"
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                image
                Color.gray.frame(height: 1000)
            }
            .background( // 1. find scrollOffset
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).minY
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewWithPullDownOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: offset)
                }
            )
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpaceName)
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewWithPullDownOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            scrollOffset = value
        }
    }

    var image: some View { frame
        GeometryReader { proxy in // 2. get actual size on screen
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill") // 3. use scrollOffset to adjust image 
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(.horizontal, min(0, -scrollOffset))
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width,
                       height: proxy.size.height + max(0, scrollOffset))
                .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: min(0, -scrollOffset)))
        }
        .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 375, height: 280), contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is code in the link to answer the question you should include that code in the answer, linking to your own products is generally considered spam.